# Invoking a program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way for a program to invoke another program in python?

Let me explain my problem:

1. I am building an application (program 1) , I am also writing a debugger to catch exceptions (program 2)  in program 1   `{ a typical try :   except: }` block of code . Now I want to release program 2  so that for any application like prog 1 , prog 2 can handle exceptions ( making my work easier) . I just want prog 1 to use a simple piece of code like:

   ```
   import prog2
   ```
2. My confusion stems from the fact as how can I do something like this , how can I invoke prog 2 in prog 1, ie  it should function as  all the code in prog 1 should run in the `{try: (prog 1) , except:}` prog 2 try block.

Any pointers on how I can do this or a direction to start would we very much appreciated.

Note: I am using python 2.7 and IDLE as my developer tool.

Comment: How does this make your work easier?  If you catch the wrong exceptions, you can have very funny bugs which are difficult to track.

Comment: Also, if the code in `prog2` are properly organized into functions, you can just `import prog2` and then  `try: prog2.run(); except ...`

Comment: as in I just want to develop prog 2 as an internal tool for anyone in my dept to use . I dnt expect to catch all kind of exceptions but to minimize some of the ones that have been haunting most of s

Comment: @mgilson I want people who dev prog 1  not get involved with prog 2 but just use it as a tool , ie just invoke it

Comment: I guess the question is, How to you expect to handle an exception that you know nothing about?  What do you plan on doing with it?

Answer (score 1):

tried `execfile()` yet? Read up on it on how to execute another script from your script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to think about classes instead of scripts.

What about this?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.property = t
        self.catchBugs()

    def catchBugs(self):
        message = self.property
        try:
            assert message == 'hello'
        except AssertionError:
            print "String doesn't match expected input"


a = MyClass('hell') # prints 'String doesn't match expected input'
```

### UPDATE

I guess you have something like this in your directory:

- `program1.py` (main program)
- `program2.py` (debugger)
- `__init__.py`

#### Program1

```
from program2 import BugCatcher

class MainClass:    
   def __init__(self, a):       
      self.property = a


obj = MainClass('hell') 
bugs = BugCatcher(obj)
```

#### Program2

```
class BugCatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.catchBugs()

    def catchBugs(self):
        obj = self.obj
        try:
            assert obj.property == 'hello'
        except AssertionError:
            print 'Error'
```

Here we are passing the whole object of your program1 to the BugCatcher object of program2. Then we access some property of that object to verify that it's what we expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , I did think of this approach but it does not address the fact that people may have their own prog 1's and manipulating prog 2 for each does not maintain uniformity in detection

Comment: Uhm, program 2 is the debugger, right? If so, then you can incorporate program 2 into program 1. Or do you want to keep program 2 separate so it can be used in other programs?

Comment: I want to keep prog 2 separate so as it can be used in other programs too ( kinda like a in house tool for my team)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation !!! , I will try it out and let you know what happens

Comment: from 
program2 import BugCatcher

class MainClass:    
   def __init__(self):       
   self.test() 
  def test():
    i=1/0;



So , Now If we want our program 1 i.e debugger to catch the exception divide by zero in the function test()
then how are we going to code it in the debugger so that it will catch the exception without explicitly using test(),I mean to ask how are we going to generalize the debugger so that it can catch all the exceptions irrespective of the .py fil its been imported by(it should work for all the .py files) without changing the content of the debugger.

Comment: Assuming you have a test method in your MainClass, then you can access to that method using the object that receives BugCatcher, right? So you could add something like try: obj.test(); except ZeroDivisionError: # do something; (that goes inside catchBugs method). That should start your method, detect that an exception occurred and do something about it.